# Add text to column description, Google Charts API

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is there a way that I can add my own text to the "speech bubbles" that hover next to a column bar when the mouse is on it, in Google Charts API?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just a matter of adding another axis to your data something like [x, y, "this is my text"]